# <script type="application/dart;component=1" ></script>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using Dart SDK 1.4.2

Does it supports

```
  <script type="application/dart;component=1" src="mylist.dart"></script>
```

or

```
 <script type="application/dart" src="mylist.dart"></script>
```

Comment: It depends on you polymer version, which do you use?

Comment: Than you should use the second case. The component=1 part was required in ealier versions.